# What is the easiest way to make a stepper motor go?

Tags: stepper-motor

What is the easiest/ cheapest way to make that motor move like a dc hobby motor would when connected to a battery? Speed doesn't matter. I just want it to infinitely rotate.

Comment: The only possible way without any components would be to manually apply power to each phase one by one, I'm not sure if that meets your idea of infinitely rotate or not. Or do you mean a pre-made stepper controller?

Comment: I edited it I worded it wrong

Comment: And by infinitely rotate I mean to not stop at a certain degree, and keep rotating

Comment: Are we talking about a stepper motor or DC motor? The two are not the same. Datasheet? What do you have on hand? Depending on the motor, this may be done with as little as a microcontroller, and maybe a few N-channel MOSFETs.

Comment: Stepper motors from printers

Comment: shopping questions are discouraged on this site

Comment: You can run a stepper motor off of low-voltage AC by using a capacitor to phase-shift one coil by 90 degrees: http://www.wzmicro.com/1compdrv.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you really are using a stepper motor (?), you'll need either a stepper motor driver, or a microcontroller and a basic current driver (chip or a few FETs). You'll also need to know whether your motor is unipolar or bipolar. Without these, there is no way to apply current to the correct coils in such a way that the motor will move. I'm always keen to suggest the [Pololu A4988](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1182). It's very simple to use, relatively inexpensive, robust, and makes driving a stepper motor almost exactly the same as a DC motor. Bringing the "STEP" pin high and leaving it there will run the motor at full speed, just like a basic DC motor. Pulsing the input allows for slower, finer rotation control. [It's also simple to drive a stepper from an Arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StepperUnipolar); All you need is an Arduino and a ULN2003A current driver or similar.

It's also useful to understand how the device you're trying to work with works. I'd suggest you check out [this quick little bit on steppers](http://www.solarbotics.net/library/pieces/parts_mech_steppers.html).

Comment: Jay - you mention making STEP high and leaving it will will run the stepper continuously.If I have that right, will this work? Using a A4988 Stepper Motor Driver, power the board with 5v, set 'STEP' to high for continuous rotation, alternate 'DIR' between high and low to change directions (probably a switch), connect 'SLEEP' to 'RESET', connect between 8 and 35v between VMOT and GND with a small cap across it, and the appropriate other motor connections on 1A 1B 2A and 2B.
Would that work?

Comment: @merlin777 you are commenting on a 5+ year old post...but to answer your question, no that will not work.  Pulling the step pin high only moves it one increment.